# Populate a List<object> in my Model from the view ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I have model that has few properties and a List of other objects.

Model Offer:

Car

Date

bla bla

### List of OfferRaws

OfferRaw:

PartCode

PartDescription

Price

---

So in my View when a user makes an offer he has to fill all The Data for the offer, But how i can take the filled info from the user to populate the data for the OfferRaws and they can be added to the List of the Model

```
 public OfferCreateViewModel()
    {
        this.Raws = new List<OfferRawCreateViewModel>();
    }

    public string CarMake { get; set; }

    public string CarModel { get; set; }

    public string CarRegistrationNumber { get; set; }

    public string CarVinNumber { get; set; }

    public string CarOwner { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OfferRawCreateViewModel> Raws { get; set; }
```

Comment: are you sure it will be list, isn't one user will put one offer?

Comment: an offer has a list of raws and every raw has properies as Part Code, Part Count Part Price and Price of work, So every offer has a client and a list of raws

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that you would like to add multiple Raws when you create an offer, and then pass all data to your controller.It could be done with the help of js. You could refer to my simple demo below.

1.My Models

```
public class OfferRawCreateViewModel
{
    public string PartCode { get; set; }
    public string PartDescription { get; set; }
}

public class OfferCreateViewModel
{
    public OfferCreateViewModel()
    {
        this.Raws = new List<OfferRawCreateViewModel>();
    }

    public string CarModel { get; set; }

    public string CarOwner { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OfferRawCreateViewModel> Raws { get; set; }
}
```

2. View

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.OfferCreateViewModel


<form asp-action="Create" method="post">
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="CarModel" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="CarModel" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="CarModel" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="CarOwner" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="CarOwner" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="CarOwner" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="item-list">
    <a href="#" id="add">Add</a>
    <br />
    <input type="text" asp-for="Raws" class="items" name="Raws[0].PartCode" />
    <input type="text" asp-for="Raws" class="items" name="Raws[0].PartDescription" />
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
</form>
@section Scripts {
<script>
$(function () {

   $("#add").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var i = ($(".items").length) / 2;
       var n = '<br /><input type="text" class="items" name="Raws[' + i + '].PartCode" />' +
           '<input type="text" class="items" name="Raws[' + i + '].PartDescription" />'

       $("#item-list").append(n);
   });

});
</script>
}
```

3.Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create(OfferCreateViewModel model)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps me a lot. But when i add more than one raw, and than i hit the create button only the first raw is added to the Model List

Comment: I have tried to add "asp-for" in the new inputs inside the JS code, but it still adding only the first raw

Comment: You could check what data has been passed to controller from F12 Network in Chrome.You need to modify the js code ` var i = ($(".items").length) / 2;`  in your real case which represents how many Raw lines there are.

Comment: I tried your code everything works fine, so may be the problem is somewhere in my code....